# How to add title using accordion jquery for Collapse and Expand

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to add title using accordion jquery function, on hover on icon it should display collapse and Expand vice versa, please see below image and code.

http://s12.postimg.org/yu5tor9m5/2015_01_19_23_17_05_j_Query_UI_Accordion_Custom.png

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Customize icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion" title="Collapse">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>  
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>  
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the collapse/expand to fire on hover rather than click event?

Comment: Your problem is that it only shows "Collapse"? That's what it shows in my browser at least.

Comment: I need to just Show Title when I just Hover on the icon.
With title name as Collapse or Expand, please see image at 
http://s12.postimg.org/yu5tor9m5/2015_01_19_23_17_05_j_Query_UI_Accordion_Custom.png